# New SSL listener port with different keystore/truststore in WebLogic

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-ee, certificate, weblogic

Is there any way to configure an additional SSL listener port on an existing WebLogic server that uses a different keystore and truststore configuration from the "main" SSL port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use multiple keystores for the same server - Even if you're using custom key/trust stores, you should be able to consolidate everything (using import/export for keytool/ikeyman).

Under the Server -> Protocols -> Channels tab, you can define an additional port using your SSL protocol of choice (t3s/https/iiops/ldaps) but your issue should be resolved by using the earlier suggestion alone.